# A committee requires one accountant, two marketing agents..

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

A committee requires one accountant, two marketing agents, and four board 
members. If there are four accountants, three marketing agents, and seven board 
members available for selection in the committee, how many committees can be 
formed?

I tried doing 4 choose 1, 3 choose 2, 7 choose 4 and nothing worked.

Can anyone show me what do to? Need to know this for my test.

Comment: Why don't you think it worked?

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt I dont know..

Comment: Take the product of your three numbers.

Comment: @jessicaJaneC, what is the answer?, I think (4 choose 1)* (3 choose 2)* (7 choose 4) is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the right factors that you need, but you need to ***multiply*** them (i.e., find their product).

$$\binom 41\cdot \binom 32\cdot \binom 74$$